# How do I build a content slider like this?

Tags: jquery

On [this page](http://www.in2headphones.com/), you'll see two elements coming in separately from each side of the slider. Is there a jQuery plugin for this or do I need to build it on my own?

Comment: That slide effect [is custom code](http://www.in2headphones.com/wp-content/themes/in2/js/slide.js?ver=3.1.1-RC1). Oftentimes with these types of professionally designed and developed sites, the code is built by developers with specific skills. You could replicate that with jQuery and jQuery Easing I'm sure, but you would have to be careful about optimization; that type of effect can be difficult to tune for performance. Also, the developers appear to be French.

Comment: [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/), [easySlider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider), [tutorial on sliding in/out](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions), plus the nifty [Banner Rotator](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-banner-rotator-slideshow/full_screen_preview/109046?ref=lvraa) and the slick [Nivo](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/). None of these specifically do what you're looking for out of the box, but they should give you the pieces/ideas as to how to construct the effect you're looking for.

Comment: The downvotes are related to the attitude some people have for questions that seem to be: under-developed or giving the appearance  the OP has given little/no effort towards resolving the problem themselves (therefore, are "helpless and/or hapless"); asking for/assuming SO contributors are code flacks here to do work for them; premature in that once the OP has worked the problem, an answer to their own question will be obvious (the lazy/dithering/decisionless/directionless); etc., etc. I wouldn't take it personally, but try to put more effort into your problem before asking the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation Jared. Also, thank you for the slide options. I will take a look through them and see if I can construct something of my own, although my JS skills are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a plugin, this site is using custom built jquery functionality... you'll need to build this on your own.

The original jquery slider was called the Coda Slider, which is named after the slider effect that is on the Panic Coda website (http://panic.com/coda/)

If you want to download a slider, go to the original slider tutorial: http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/

Also for more tutorials about these types of animations, you can check out [jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes.